# Preventing an element from being dragged past the bottom and right of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that makes any element passed into it draggable. I have already successfully bounded the element from the left and top of the screen in `elementDrag(e)`:

```
element.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(minLeft, calcLeft), maxRight) + "px";
element.style.top = Math.min(Math.max(minTop, calcTop), maxBottom) + "px";
```

But calculating the appropriate right and bottom positions for the element has proven difficult. How can I prevent an element from being dragged past the right and bottom of the screen? Here is the code:

```
function dragElement(element) {
let pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

if (document.getElementById(element.id + "-header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(element.id + "-header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
} else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}

function dragMouseDown(e) {
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
}

function elementDrag(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    // get the boundaries of the parent div and the element's offsets
    const rect = document.querySelector("#viewDiv").getBoundingClientRect();
    const minLeft = rect.left;
    const minTop = rect.top;
    const maxRight = rect.right;
    const maxBottom = rect.bottom;
    let calcTop = element.offsetTop - pos2;
    let calcLeft = element.offsetLeft - pos1;

    // set the element's new position
    // use the rectangular boundaries of the viewDiv and the element's offsets as constraints
    element.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(minLeft, calcLeft), maxRight) + "px";
    element.style.top = Math.min(Math.max(minTop, calcTop), maxBottom) + "px";
}
```